# Obtaining the triadic closure of a Graph with graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am trying to build the triadic closure of a graph-tool `Graph`.

`graph_tool.topology` contains `transitive_closure`, which is basically the "infinite-th" power of the adjacency matrix: what I need is the second, or in general the `k`-th, power.

Is there some better way than just... calculating the powers of the adjacency matrix?

Comment: This sounds like a good addition to the library. Please open a feature request issue.

Comment: Done: https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/issues/299